# IE focus when div is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

My goal is to simulate the behavior of jquery "datepicker" but instead of showing a calendar, I want to show a selectable table.

I have a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dz9VC/) in chrome and FF but not in IE8 :( (I don't know if you guys can run fiddles with IE but if you can't, please make a local copy and open with IE, thanks)

**Problems:**

1. in IE, when I scroll, the div is hidden so I fixed it with

   ```
           $("#test_table_container").scroll(function() {
               if (myTimeOut) {
                   clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
               }
           });
   ```

   but when I click on the scrollbar (instead of dragging it), the div is hidden. This is also the same when click the arrow buttons. This does not happen though if I drag the scroll bar FIRST, THEN click on the scroll bar.
2. the timout duration (90ms) is unfortunately very intermittent, sometimes I am able to select values in tr and then the div is hidden, but sometimes the div is hidden FIRST, before the click event of tr is triggered that's why the value is not reflected in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need for a `setTimeout` hack for this. You may be better off, by binding a `click` on the body and then use delegation.

Please see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dz9VC/1/

This is just a crude code, but you will get the idea and can then optimize it as per your need. The updated fiddle should work on IE as well. The reason it wasn't working in IE8 specifically, maybe due to the box-model differences.

Comment: thanks for the input, although I am not understanding some terms you've used, I will look them up! ("delegation" and "box-model differences") haha

Comment: thanks it works. but follow-up question, is this acceptable performance-wise? checking every click of the background?

Comment: Definitely. Rather than hooking up several event handlers, we are having just one. Events bubble up. So, if multiple event handlers are not crafted carefully, there are good chances of performance degradation anyway. By having one handler at a higher level we are simply exploiting the bubbling by using event-delegation i.e. identifying the target of event (which element generated the event) and then coding against the specific ones. In this case body `click` has to be watched-for in any case (to hide the dropdown). So, instead of separate event handlers, we are simply using the same handler.